# Multiple form in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5

Here I am trying to create a single form through which I want to save multiple data by one key press. For this I have created form in tabular format.

[image]

When i try to add date it is supplied inform of array to controller as below:-

[image]

But it gets rollback if i try to save it.
Here i am using nested form so that i can save multiple data to second form.

```
def new
    @purchase = Purchase.new
    @purchase_item = @purchase.purchase_items.build
    @item = Item.order(:name)
  end

  def create
    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
    if @purchase.save
      flash[:success] = "Items added."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Items not added."
    end
    redirect_to :new_purchase
  end
 def purchase_params
    params.require(:purchase).permit(:vendor_id, purchase_items_attributes: [ :purchase_id , :item_id , :quantity, :unit_price ])
  end
```

So, problem is that i want to eliminate rollback and want to save data.  Can anyone help me to solve this problem.

Application log after i submit my form:-

[image]

Comment: check if you have added any validations in model, that might be restricting it from getting it save.

Comment: sry but i have not used any validations till now...

Comment: ok can u please paste your application logs, so that it will be helpful for everyone whoever are viewing this question.

Comment: Please check above picture... are you asking for same...

Comment: No the logs which are shown in your terminal or development.log file.

Comment: last picture is screenshot of application log.... shown in my terminal...

Comment: Vendor_id is empty in params.

Comment: We need you to past Purchase and Item models. You can use a gist on gist.github.com instead of making screenshots...

Comment: Usually I have this rollback error when I am trying to save an object (purchase) which has foreign key with another object (item), so before saving I need to input that foreign key and save both. In your case you have a join, but when you do the create method, maybe you should first create those items? I mean do not create a Purchase with join purchase_items = [ a, b, c] if items = [a, b, c] do not exist. Maybe I am wrong

Comment: @Shitalluitel Please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276740/ruby-nested-form/41277270#41277270), maybe you are missing `inverse_of `.

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio i think you got it... but i can't understand... plz could you explain more clearly to me

Comment: I posted my answer, but I am rethinking about it. I think your purpose is to create that item on the purchase with one command `@purchase = Purchase.new`, still the problem you are having is with the join or those nested attributes.

Comment: are you sure that you are using the correct syntax? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702783/rails-strong-params-using-fields-from-has-many-object

Comment: So do you have an update?

Answer (score 1):

The customer is making a purchase, this means he is selecting items that you already have created. He has to chose the item he want to purchase with this section box (the one where you read select one)

[image]

I have something similar in my app, I use this code for the input field:

```
<%= f.select(:item_id, Item.all.collect {|i| [ i.name, i.id ]}, {include_blank: 'Select an existing Item', selected: "Select an existing Project"}, {:class => "form-control"}) %>
```

What I mean is that when the user selects this fields, the field should only show a list of possible entries from the items table with which you created the join.

I also do not find any detail in your post about foreign key with another table and join. I have done something like this and I have created a `has_many` relationship between Purchase and Item.
So Purchase has_many :items means that items table and item model with have a foreign key with Purchase model named purchase_id..

The process will be :

1. Create the Items that you want to sell (without filling the foreign key purchase_id) `item = Item.create()`
2. Create a new Purchase `purchase = Purchase.new()`
3. Change the foreign key to the items that will be part of the purchase and save `item.purchase_id = purchase.id` `item.save`
4. `purchase.save`

If you save an Item with a non existing purchase_id you will get the **rollback**. This is one way to solve this, it is how I have done it, with separate table and I think it makes sense, because Item has many attributes and you will keep track of those.

It would make sense if you can save Item without having a purchase_id.

Hear is an example of the controller

**Creating item**

```
def create
   @item = Item.new(item_params)
   @item.save
   etc...
end
```

**Creating purchase**

```
def create
    @purchase = Purchase.new(purchase_params)
    if @purchase.save
      flash[:success] = "Items added."
    else
      flash[:error] = "Items not added."
    end
    redirect_to :new_purchase
end
```

You are free to solve this how you want, but the idea is that the **rollback may be caused by the non existence of the items you are referencing**