# Rails strong params - using fields from has_many object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

thanks a lot for your help.

In my **rails** project I have:

- A **location** Model that **has many :ads**

  ```
  class Location < ApplicationRecord
      has_many :ads, :dependent => :destroy
  end
  ```
- The **Ad** Model
- In the controller **developer_controller.rb** I need to use with **strong params** the fields from **location** and **ad**

  ```
   params.require(:location).permit(:country, :location, {:ads => [:remote, :days]})
  ```

I don't know how to retrieve correctly the fields **remote** and **days** from the ad object.

Thanks a lot

Clinton

Comment: You should be able too loop through the ads and access remote and days from there.  You may want to add you Ad Model, and show more of the controller and views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to use **_attributes**:

```
 params.require(:location).permit(:country, :location, {:ads_attributes => [:remote, :days]})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help