# How to get nested value in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I just make some change to db structure, and have to use nested model

post model

```
has_many :pictures
accepts_nested_attributes_for :pictures, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

picture model

```
belongs_to :user
```

in view (rendered 1 input field)

```
= f.simple_fields_for :pictures, @post.pictures.build do |e|
    = e.input :picture, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, label: false
```

question is: How could I get value of input :picture in post model. I tried few things but none of them works.

Thank in advance

Comment: So do you have an update?

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio just got 2 days off and get back to work today. i'll let you know the result later :)

Answer (score 1):

with rails 5 first thing you will need to do is in your controller use strong params with nested attributes

```
def post_params
 params.require(:post).permit(:firstfield, :secondfield, {:pictures_attributes => [:picture, :firstattribute, :secondattribute]})
end
```

[Rails strong params - using fields from has_many object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42702783/rails-strong-params-using-fields-from-has-many-object) I am crediting **David**

If you want to access the value you will find it in

```
post_params[:pictures_attributes][i][:picture]
```

because when in your form use `do |e|` that will create a nested attribute that could have many rows. I use `i` to select a row.

That is my understanding of the problem.

Comment: got this error: undefined local variable or method `post_params' for #<Post

Comment: @ŌkamiXOukarin maybe you have this error because you did not create the instance of `@post = Post.new` and `@post.pictures.build` in your controller before calling it.
I read about this some days ago in a discussion. If you could give me some additional informations by editing your post with a screenshot and the updated code you are using . thanks

Comment: so post.pictures.build in simple field for is not enough

Comment: @ŌkamiXOukarin sorry, but you need to edit the question with a screenshot and the updated code. Additional infos will also be very useful