# when i try to create a job, it will show error in views/jobs/_form.html.erb Company must exist, company name should populate automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :company
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :c_name
      t.text :c_description
      t.integer:user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

# Models
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :companies
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category
    belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to:user
    has_many:jobs

end

# Jobs controller
def show
        end

        def new

               @job = current_user.jobs.build       
        end

def create
        job_attrs = jobs_params.except(:company)
        job_attrs[:company] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:company])
        @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_attrs)

      if @job.save
        flash[:success]= "success"
        redirect_to @job

        else

        flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
        render "new"
        end
    end

def jobs_params
            params.require(:job).permit(:title, :description, :company, :category_id, :image,:jobclosedate,:company_id)
end
```

this is the views/jobs/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job,validation:true ,html: { mutlipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control"}%>
<%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
<%= f.input :company, label: "Your Company", input_html: { class: "form-control" }%>
<%= f.collection_select :category_id,Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" }%>
```

When I try to create a job, it will show in views/jobs/_form.html.erb

> "Company must exist" (job/_form will not get the company name from company module )
>   company should populate automatically in the views/jobs/_form.html.erb, it will not automatically populated and it'show company mush exit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ruby Nested Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41276740/ruby-nested-form)

Comment: i'm new to the ruby, how may i solve this issue

Comment: you can check my answer in linked question.

Comment: thanks a lot, i was try that .it's not working,

Comment: can you share view code?

Comment: thanks , i have updated with view codes

Comment: {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"sIDh09A44jnisIkJnhiZqkzyr8I6Y4ZAv1gukED7ut9Il7xt2W4Q6U3rFG76RwcfTHS8PvSBauNXRio1DUddUg==",
 "job"=>{"title"=>"test test", "description"=>"aaaaaaa aaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "companies"=>{"c_name"=>"virtusa coperation"}, "category_id"=>"1", "jobclosedate"=>"02/06/2018"},
 "commit"=>"Create Job"} company name and company id  valuesnnare not pass